# self signed certificate expiration for android apps

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I was wondering if is possible to make a self signed certificate
on my server, so that my app can communicate via ssl (I am aware
of methods how to make my app trust the self signed cert, so that
the certificate would not expire in 1 year but maybe in 5 as I don't
want to manually update many apps that would use ssl.

IS there any way to make a self signed certificate that doesn't
expire within 1 year? If not, would there be any point in making
my app download the new cert if a certain date has passed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're completely free to set whatever you want for expiry time when you create/sign a certificate.

Here's how to generate a self signed SSL certificate using Ruby. I personally prefer to use a language binding when talking to OpenSSL since the CLI is a bit complicated to use :)

```
require "openssl"

keypair = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
File.open("/tmp/key.pem", "w+") do |f|
  f.write ca_keypair.to_pem(OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-128-CBC"), "my passphrase")
end

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
cert.not_before = Time.now
cert.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.new([
    ["C", "NO"],
    ["ST", "Oslo"],
    ["L", "Oslo"],
    ["CN", "August Lilleaas"]
  ])
cert.issuer = cert.subject
cert.not_after = Time.now + 1000000000 # 40 or so years
cert.public_key = keypair.public_key

File.open("/tmp/cert.pem", "w+") do |f|
  f.write cert.to_pem
end
```